# Interview norms in the United Kingdom

Tags: interviewing, united-kingdom

In a short while I will be interviewing for development / research roles in technological firms in the UK. I am trying to understand what are interview norms peculiar to the UK versus the rest of the world, and especially compared to Israeli norms.

By interview norms I mean anything from the way of presenting yourself and past achievements to interpersonal dynamics.

Comment: What are Israeli norms so we can compare?

Comment: It is hard for me to say what exactly are Israeli norms as I do not have experience with other cultures' norms

Answer (score 3):

There are no specific interviewing norms in the UK beyond the obvious basics:

- Be prepared to discuss and demonstrate your skills (with examples of prior work/challenges)
- Be prepared to be asked about aspects of your CV/resume
- Be presentable
- Be on time
- Be polite
- Do research on the company you're interviewing for (this will be expected)
- Show them in what way you can add value to their business

Comment: You may be asked questions like "Tell us about a time you had to resolve a conflict within a team?". These type of "experience" questions are common and employers are looking for you to explain how you dealt with a scenario rather than just asking "Have you ever managed a team?".